# grep ignoring pipe when aliased to 'grep -R'

Tags: shell, grep, pipe, alias

I'm trying to pipe the output of a grep search into the input of another grep.
Such as:

```
grep search_query * | grep -v but_not_this
```

But the second grep is not using the output of the previous search. It looks like the second grep is just using * instead. For example,

```
grep lcov *                                                                                          
tst/bits/Module.mk:21:$(call func_report_lcov)
tst/drivers/Module.mk:27:$(call func_report_lcov)
```

But when I want to filter out the results containing "call",

```
grep lcov * | grep -v call
...
```

Grep gives me *every single line in my workspace* that doesn't contain "call".

**Environment Info:**

- This is happening in both bash and fish
- I have aliased the grep command like so `alias grep='grep -nR --color=always'`

Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: `grep` does not descend into subdirectories without the `-r/-R` option. Do you have a function or script named `grep`? What does `type -a grep` show (in bash)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alias is what is causing it. From `man grep`, the `-R` option causes `grep` to "read all files under each directory, recursively". Hence, the part after the pipe ignores the output from the first `grep`, and instead `grep`s through all files recursively from the current directory.

You can bypass the alias and use vanilla grep with `\grep`. Hence the following should give you what you expect.

```
grep lcov * | \grep -v call
```

However, I personally think that putting `-R` in the alias is confusing.

Comment: The main issue here is that GNU `grep`, when using `-R` and when not given a filename operand, will act recursively on the contents of the current directory. Other `grep` implementations don't use `.` as the default file operand when `-R` is used and no file operand is given (OpenBSD `grep`, for example, complains with `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin`).

Comment: In a script you could use `/bin/grep` or `$(which grep)` instead to make sure there is no alias set.

Comment: @Freddy Generally scripts wouldn't source `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Oh yes, how true.

Comment: It's not confusing, it's wacky

Comment: @Kusalananda, BSDs `grep` used to be GNU `grep`. Those which rewrote their `grep` later preserved the API, but that was from an older GNU `grep`. GNU `grep` defaulting to `.` with `-r`/`-R` when not given any argument is relatively recent ([2012](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=faf6ea13b3281a2004f5bfd1487708d1ba50a6c5), 2.11 while BSDs forked or stopped using GNU grep around 2.5 IIRC)

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. This *appears* to be correct, looks like the devil's in the details.

```
grep "search_query" *
```

*could be* different than

```
grep search_query *
```

which *could be* different again from

```
grep 'search_query' *
```

Try this:

```
grep search_query * > /tmp/foo
grep -v but_not_this /tmp/foo
```

Does the file `/tmp/foo` contain what you want?
Does `grep -v but_not_this` give the answer you want?
replace `grep` with `\grep` to unalias it it and see if that works.

Comment: Why "could be different"? All the three commands are the same, right? What difference does single/double-quoting make here?

Comment: It has to do with substitutions. If you are using $ or special characters.
Double quotes mean "Substitute Now." Single quotes mean 'Let the program do the substitution.'
Suppose I set my_var to Scottie.  
grep "$my_var" foo becomes  
grep Scottie foo
But grep '$my_var' foo  
looks for the word $my_var in the file foo

Comment: Yes, but in the question it's just a string `lcov`.

Comment: Have you triedto unalias both greps? useing the backslash on BOTH greps? Or unaliasing the grep completely <br>  
If you send the first gerp to a file, does that file contain what you expect?<br>  
If rou run the second grep on the file, do you get the correct result?

Comment: Because you have -R in the grep, you are searching EVER non-hidden file in your current directory and EVERY non-hidden SUBdirectory. To see what I mean, run this command:  
_ls -R *_
Are ALL of those the files you want to grep?