# Unable to grep piped output

Tags: grep

I am able to use ripgrep to do things like this:

`ps aux | rg 'process name'`

I am able to search the output of the previous command. For some reason this doesn't work for me using regular `grep`. If I do:

`ps aux | grep 'process name'`

It ignores what I am trying to pipe into grep and searches the current working directory for the process I typed in.

This is the output of ps aux:
[image: ps aux output]

If I would grep firefox for example it would not show it.

`ps aux | rg firefox` gives me this:
[image: ps aux with rg]

EDIT: It seems to be because some sort of alias
described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500727/375504

This works: `ps aux | \grep firefox`

Comment: Can you add the output from `ps aux` and the name of a process that shows up in that output but cannot be found by grep? A copy from the terminal, with commands and everything would help a lot.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, ilkkachu I added an example

Comment: What do you get with `type grep`

Comment: @guillermochamorro: grep is aliased to `grep -nRi '

Comment: ...that's an insane thing to alias. (personal opinion, of course)

Comment: @ilkkachu yeah I don't remember why and when I put that in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that when you use `ps aux | grep 'process name'` *it (`grep`) ignores what I am trying to pipe into grep and searches the current working directory*.

You also write that *grep is aliased to `grep -nRi`*.

When you look at the documentation for `grep` (`man grep`) you will find that the `-R` flag does exactly what you have described:

> `-r`, `--recursive` Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the  command  line. [...]

and

> `-R`, `--dereference-recursive` Read all files under each directory, recursively.  Follow all symbolic links, unlike `-r`

With GNU grep, `grep -r` also by default starts from the current directory if a filename argument is not given. Some other versions of grep don't do that, but might instead warn about a "recursive search of stdin" while still reading stdin.

The solution is not to alias `grep` to something else. Instead create a new alias if you need specific functionality (`rgrep` could be an alternative here, for example).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had aliased `grep` to `grep -nRi $*` in my bash aliases. Removing the alias or calling `\grep` fixes the issue.